# Why doesn't our solar system run into other solar systems over billions of years?

Tags: estimation, solar-system, milky-way

Why doesn't our solar system run into other solar systems over billions of years.
There is plenty of time for it to be attracted by gravity to other objects. So I thought, it should be a common occurrence? or is there a reason it is not a common occurrence?

Comment: Stars orbit the galaxy's centre, a supermassive black hole, so they don't really draw one another together in a collision-inducing manner. They also occupy so little of the galaxy's volume it's likely the Milky Way's eventual merge with Andromeda won't cause any collisions either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind- bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.

Douglas Adams, *Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*

Comment: Geeks think the same way. I was coming to quote the same line. But you should note that it's from Douglas Adams.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision  for galaxy collision

Comment: @annav True, but that's because of gravity. When galaxies collide, stars and solar systems _still_ don't collide. :O